# '%' not being accepted in string to sever php code

Tags: c#, php

I'm writing and reading a .txt file from a server using C# and .php file, below my C#

```
IEnumerator writeString()
{
    string mycontent = "42.00 £3.80 sending test string";
    url = "http://www.myServer.com/ewExternalFiles/writeScript.php?txt=" + mycontent;

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    progress = www.progress;

    while(progress < 1)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("successfully written to server ..");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error! (" + www.error + ")");
    }
}
```

My .php code

```
<?php
$txtcontent = $_REQUEST['txt'];
$fp = fopen("file.txt", w);
fwrite($fp, $txtcontent);
echo $fp;
fclose($fp);
?>
```

when reading it back all works fine, but if I change the line

```
string mycontent = "42.00 £3.80 sending test string";
```

to

```
string mycontent = "42.00% £3.80 sending test string";
```

I get the error

> 'Error! (400 Bad Request)'

from the server because of the % in the string, can I not have this in my string? Tanks.

Comment: `%` has a special meanings in URLs.... so urlencode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

```
string mycontent = WebUtility.UrlEncode("42.00% £3.80 sending test string");
```

The UrlEncode method is designed to receive a string and replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Comment: As I'm using Unity3D WWW.EscapeURL() to send the string and WWW.UnEscapeURL() to receive the string done the trick, thanks.